# Position div under another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs: div with submit and order-content div

```html
    <div class="order">
        <form>
        <div class="input">submit</div>
        </form>
        
        <div class="order-content">
        <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
          <div class="new-product">
              <div class="product-add">
                  <form>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Also when I add new product, im appending new table row, so css position attribute doesn't work as I want cause it has static values. I thought about making jquery which gets height of new row and increments submit input position, but is there better solution?

Comment: Could you detail which div you want to place under which other please? This seems very unclear.

Comment: I want to place input div: <div class="input">submit</div> UNDER <div class="order-content">

Comment: Can you move where it is in the html?

Comment: @freedomn-m no I cant because its inside form which closes before order-content begins

Comment: You can use jquery/js to submit a form from a button outside that form.  It's hard to tell what content is in `<div class='input'>submit</div>`  that needs to be in the form.    Could you extend `form` to include `order-content`?

Comment: @freedomn-m thats a perfect solution to submit a form with button outside this form! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to move elements in DOM to a different order than they appear in the original document. Something like (jsfiddle with jQuery):

https://jsfiddle.net/khabgc6h/2/

```
$('.input').insertAfter('.new-product')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".input").click(function(){
 $("#table").append('<tr><td>Data</td></tr>')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="order">
 <div  class="col-xs-12 form-group">
 
 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <button class="btn input">
        submit
        </button></div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 order-content">
        <table id="table" class="form-group"><tr><td>Data</td></tr></table>
          <div class="new-product">
              <div class="product-add">
                  <form>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```